# Submission of ios app: invalid team id

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a problem with the submission of an ios app on my customer itunes connect account.

Let me describs current accounts:

- My Apple Id account is joined into my organization Apple Id as admin.
- My customer has joined me in their itunes connect account with technical role.

Now I need to submit my developed app to the itunes connect account of my customer.

In xcode, I have Archive and Export binaries using my apple id (and a team id).

When I use Application Loader to submit the IPA, Apple reject my build with this error:
"Invalid team id in signature - The code signature in bundle 'BUNDLE_ID' at 'APP_NAME' has a team identifier value that is different from your team identifier '26RWXXXXXX'."

Think is normal because I want to send a signed app with with apple id account to another itunes connect account.

But how can I submit with only itunes connect account?

My customer is strict on this: "I only need the iTunes Connect account to submit the app".

Help Please.

Comment: Why downvoted? Seems a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered exactly the same error today. It turns out that the client has to add the developer in both iTunes Connect and developer.apple.com/membercenter/ > People > Invitations (I missed this). Otherwise the new team will not appear in Xcode > Preference > Accounts. Only when the new team shows up, you can then sign the app with new team ID.

Answer (score 0):

In your Xcode export the binary by logging in as Admin.Xcode>> Preferences>> Account. 
Hope you know how to create the distribution certificate

For more info look into this.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Comment: Problem is that I don't have access to Admin account of my customer.