# Xcode - How to upload build to a specific team

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

My Apple ID is associated with two different teams on iTunes Connect, so how can I sign and upload a build for a specific team?

I am in Admin and Legal role in team A, which I've been using and uploading builds to for more than a year without any issue. Recently I was invited into someone else's team (team B) as an Admin. But when I try to upload a build for an app in team B I got this error:

> ERROR ITMS-90159: "Invalid provisioning profile. This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID XXXXXXXXX."

So what should I do to get this done?

Comment: I have this exact problem too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @SimonPickup Hi Simon please check my answer below and see if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved this problem myself. I don't know if it's the correct way of doing this and I am not sure if it's a good practice, but it works and I've successfully submitted the app.

First I asked the Legal Role at the team for his iPhone distribution certificate. This can be exported as a `.p12` file. There are lots of tutorials and guides on how to export it.

After receiving the `.p12` file I extract it and install the certificate into my Keychain Access.

After the installation you should have this in your Keychain Access, where the blurred part is the name of your team Legal role.

[image]

Then I asked him for the provisioning profile of the app (ask him to create one if he hasn't). This is a `.mobileprovision` file.

Finally, in Xcode, uncheck the "Automatically manage signing" checkbox, and select the provisioning profile you received manually.

[image]

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34540861/6426003

I needed to be invited to be a member of the developer account AS well as itunes Connect, and then to create an iOS Distribution certificate. Having loaded that into Keychain Access, and restarting Xcode, I then had the new team as another choice in the drop-down.

Actually I'm now getting another error.. so I'll save this for now and update as I learn more.